# Function<T> for specific and not generics

Tags: c#

I was looking at Automapper source code and still couldn't get the info I want.

I want to map an object into 2 different dtos.

```
public class UserOrderDto {
    // common properties like UserId
    int OrderAmount { get; set; }
}

public class UserContactDto {
    // common properties like UserId
    string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
}
```

so I have :

```
internal static UserOrderDto Map(User user) { ... }
```

now I want to have another map like :

```
internal static UserContactDto Map(User user) { ... }
```

Of course that doesn't work because Map is ambiguous, so I tryied to make Map return type explicit like :

```
internal static UserOrderDto Map<UserOrderDto>(User user) { ... }
internal static UserContactDto Map<UserContactDto>(User user) { ... }
```

To my surprise this doesn't work, so I'm sure I'm getting the <> syntax incorrectly.

but this does :

```
internal static T Map<T>(User user) { ... }
```

I'm not interested on returning T, I know I want to return a specific type for each method.

Is it possible to have such scenario without using reflection and switch on a generic type ?

I know I can change the name of the function like `MapToUserOrderDto` and `MapToUserContactDto` but I think that's ugly api for other developers and myself because nothing stops you from doing `MapToPapafrita` and return `Ketchup`.

I guess `Automapper` uses reflection ... (?)

**editted with less abstract dtos**

Comment: Why is having distinctly named functions for mapping to distinct types ugly? That seems clearer to me.

Comment: @NWard because you are referencing the return type by a method name instead of the type itself.

Comment: Whats the relationship between UserDto and UserDto2

Comment: @Shoe no relationship, they have some common and some different properties. We *can* say that UserDto is a subset of UserDto2

Comment: Is there anything common between `UserDto` and `UserDto2` like an interface?

Comment: @ja72 updated with more meaningfull dtos, they *can* share an interface, but I want to be able to operate on particular properties for each one after doing the Map.

Comment: Even if you restrict T to a common interface, you'll have to cast on the other side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about this:

```
public class User
{
    public User(string id) { this.ID=id; }
    public string ID
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }
}

public interface IUserDto
{
    public string UserID { get; }
    public void SetUser(User user);
}

public class UserOrderDto : IUserDto
{
    public string UserID { get; private set; }
    public void SetUser(User user) { UserID=user.ID; }
    int OrderAmount { get; set; }
}

public class UserContactDto : IUserDto
{
    public string UserID { get; private set; }
    public void SetUser(User user) { UserID=user.ID; }
    string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    internal static T Map<T>(User user) where T : IUserDto, new()
    {
        T map=new T();
        map.SetUser(user);
        return map;
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var user=new User("Mary");
        var map=Map<UserContactDto>(user);
    }
}
```

Comment: I like it and I'm really impressed on this solution. Unfortunately, the actual mapping involves a `Expression<Func<User, UserContactDto>>` which complicates things when having a `SetUser` method.

Comment: Maybe post another question with the specific expression initialization and there might be another solution using `Expression.Body` etc

Answer (score 3):

No, you cannot do what you are trying to do.

To start with, *functions cannot be overloaded based solely on return type.*

The reason your first attempt failed, as you pointed out, is that the method calls are ambiguous. You have the same named method with the same parameter, and the only distinction is return type. This isn't allowed in C#: you need to do something else to make the signature distinct.

One solution to this is to make the method generic, which allows the generic type parameter to become the discriminator. But making the method generic requires *having a generic type parameter* in the signature. This is why your second attempt failed: you didn't include any unbound type parameters in your signature.

With a generic method, you specify the concrete type at the call site, not at the method definition. In other words, you'd *call* this method using the syntax:

```
var dto = Map<User2Dto>(user);
```

Which means, ultimately, you're probably much better off just having separately named methods to begin with.

Comment: for the record, it's *possible* to do something close to what you want in a single method, but it's incredibly ugly, fragile, and rife for abuse (it involves  using `typeof()` to invoke the correct helper methods that return `object` and are upcast back to `T`. Not pretty)

Comment: @Bart It's not very surprising you can't map a method by it's return type. I mean what would you expect `var obj = Map(user);` to return in your example?

Comment: @Shoe I wasn't expecting to call `Map(user)` but `Map<UserContactDto>(user)`.

Comment: If I remember my C++ right, you're basically asking about "template specializations". That works in C++ because templates are separate compile-time things. C# generics only get 1 type, the parameter binding doesn't happen until run-time, so they don't work the same.